# Is there a way to see which user is logged into the system and has switched with "su"?

Tags: command-line, ps, su

There are many person that may have access to the system and use a common user with more grants. How can I see which user is running a command? is there a way to use "ps" for that?

Comment: Check the same question on SO: [How can I see the loggedin users that have used 'su'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729318/how-can-i-see-the-loggedin-users-that-have-used-su).

Answer (score 1):

Using sudo instead of su to grant privileges allows you to have detailed log records in secure log (/var/log/secure in rhel-like distros). 
For example, userabc types 'sudo vi /etc/group', the log record is:

```
Jan 15 13:41:12 vm02 sudo:   userabc : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/userabc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/vi /etc/group
```